# IFRAME with HTA prompt with VB

Tags: vb.net, iframe, hta

I have an HTA prompt with VB code. I would like a URL loaded within the HTA window when the "SUBMIT" button is clicked. However, I cannot find any information that is helpful for my situation. Can someone please help me include an iframe in my HTA prompt so that a website can be displayed? I can use https://www.google.com as an example. Let me know if you have any questions.

Here is the code I currently have for the submit button:

```
bodystring = bodystring & "<BR><BR><BUTTON CLASS='Bttn_Back' OnClick='PrevStage()'>BACK</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;<BUTTON CLASS='Bttn_Submit' OnClick='NextStage()'>SUBMIT SURVEY</BUTTON>"
```

Here is my section of code for the "NextStage()" function:

```
            ElseIf STAGE = 62 Then
                SaveResults()
                Window.Close()
            End If
```

Comment: What is "an HTA prompt"? A window opened by HTA? A dialog? A `window.prompt()` window? Something else? Just a sidenote, you can't load www.google.com to an iframe, they do everything to prevent that.

Comment: I have a computer inventory survey prompt that is HTA. At the end of the survey, I would like a site opened when the SUBMIT button is clicked within that same HTA. Is that possible? Someone in my company said I should be able to do it via iframe.

Comment: So the prompt is another HTA, and you want to load a new (HTML?) document to opener HTA from a server?

Comment: My survey is already within an HTA. I just want to open an HTML document and have it displayed within that same HTA.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need. Maybe create an empty `iframe` to the HTA, hide it. Then in `nextStage()` change the `src` of the `iframe` and show it. You should not close the window though.

Comment: I am not familiar with iframe. That is what I need help with. This is exactly what I need: at the end of the survey, within the same HTA, I want an HTML file opened when the "SUBMIT" button is clicked. That HTML file should be opened within that same HTA.

Answer (score 0):

Put this to the HTML of the HTA:

```
<iframe id="htmlhere" src="" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Then in `nextStage()`:

```
document.getElementById("htmlhere").src = "http:/..."; // Loads a new document to iframe
document.getElementById("htmlhere").style.display = ""; // Setting style.display empty shows the iframe
```

Sorry for using JS, but my VB skills are more or less zero.